# Custom Java Annotation not working with Kotlin project

Tags: java, android, kotlin, annotations, kotlin-java-interop

I am writing an Android app and created a Java file with an annotation that I am using in Kotlin classes.  I am using `kapt` annotation processor.

Everything seems to show no errors in the compiler, but when I run the app, I get an error:
`incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation` - `@error.NonExistentClass()`

Is this just a `kapt` limitation?  I read something about how Kotlin stubs out functions (but I think keeps declaration site).  So that might mean it doesn't know what to do since the parameter in function declaration is marked with the annotation?

See: [kapt replaces generated class references with error.NonExistentClass despite kapt.correctErrorTypes being enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56995740/kapt-replaces-generated-class-references-with-error-nonexistentclass-despite-kap)
Any ideas how to resolve this?

Java Annotation File:

```
@IntDef(value = {Typeface.NORMAL, Typeface.BOLD, Typeface.ITALIC, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface MyTypefaceAnnotation { }
```

Kotlin Usage File:

```
sealed class MySealedClass(
    @StringRes val text: Int,
    @MyTypefaceAnnotation val typeface: Int,
    @ColorRes val fontColor: Int,
    val isEnrollmentButtonEnabled: Boolean
) {
    object NotSelected :
         MySealedClass (
            R.string.please_select,
            Typeface.NORMAL,
            R.color.light_grey,
            false
        )

// etc
```

Comment: Is the Java Annotation File really a .java File? Looks like Kotlin, so maybe it needs a extension change to ".kt"? Maybe you also need "@Target(ElementType.FIELD)" or similar for the Annotation class.

Comment: It is Java, yes.  How does it look like kotlin to you?  Notice the `public` and `@interface`, instead of `annotation class`.  Tried different @Target() types, including ElementType.FIELD) but same error.